# Yii2. Language picker widget not working properly

Tags: ajax, yii2

I use `\lajax\languagepicker` in `Yii2`.
`Languagepicker dropdown` located in `header` `nav` inside `<li>` element.

```
$menuItems [] = '<li>'.LanguagePicker::widget(['skin' => LanguagePicker::SKIN_DROPDOWN, 'size' => LanguagePicker::SIZE_LARGE,
            'itemTemplate' => '<li><a href="{link}" title="{language}"><i class="{language}"></i></a></li>',
            'activeItemTemplate' => '<a href="{link}" title="{language}" class="active"><i class="{language}"></i></a>',
            ]).'</li>';
```

`Language` of `website` is changing only when I add below `code` to the `view` being rendered:

```
use \lajax\languagepicker\widgets\LanguagePicker;
LanguagePicker::widget();
```

If above `code` is not added `Language` does not change.
I suspect it can be related to `ajax` loading.
What could be a problem?

Comment: you  are referring to the fact you must add in you sorce code file the ref. `use \lajax\languagepicker\widgets\LanguagePicker;`   ?  .without this ref you get an error ..?

Comment: I tried to add it to layout. But it does not work. It starts to work after adding a line `LanguagePicker::widget();` to view only.

Comment: It was neccessary to include `'bootstrap' => ['languagepicker']` to main config.

Comment: You have not registered the widget in config?

Comment: This line was commented in my code... So I forgot about it somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Check your DB in user table column **language**
Add it if not exist.
After that LanguagePicker start working for me.